# Angular 6 website not working on IE but works locally on all browsers

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, polyfills

- Angular 6 website
- VMware virtual machine environment
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard server

I have an angular website working fine in chrome browser (all versions) on my laptop

- Same angular website works fine in IE in my laptop (all versions) in my laptop
- But when i deploy this in client server, virtual machine, chrome website works fine
- But IE website give white blank page for all versions (all VMs in the data center)
- There is no errors in console nor warnings
- relevant polyfills.ts lines are uncommented

I changed the mode of IE to compatibility and observed following errors in console:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'Promise' is undefined
jspdf.min.js (118,654)
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
main.js (8527,59)
SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script
zone.js (2775,1)
```

Comment: did you un-comment relevant rows in the polyfills.ts ?

Comment: can you give me more informations

Comment: For testing purpose, Can you try to host any sample web page with the similar configuration and than try to access it with your virtual machine environment to check whether you are able to access it without any issue. It can be possible that it may be any configuration related issue.

Comment: Since i dont have access to IIS , this also not possible

Comment: i have edited my question, i got few errors in compatability mode only in IE hosted in VM environment.

Comment: Please check whether you are also getting similar errors on other machine on which your site is working with IE in compatibility mode. If it working without any compatibility mode than you not need to add it in compatibility mode on problematic machine. You can try to find any difference in the configuration of IE on working and non working machine may give some idea about the cause for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To get Angular App working on IE, go to polyfills.ts and uncomment the following

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: the final built works for you locally in IE in your laptop? but not when you deploy to your VM, is that it?

Comment: yes , it works fine in my laptop , for all IE versions

Comment: When i hosted in my laptop IIS its works without any issues

Comment: Looks like issues is with zones and security settings, i am not admin and dont have acceess to change these settings. any idea where and what to change the settings

Comment: there can be many things here... (1) is the site HTTPS? (2) go to IE on the VM and tools > internet options > securty settings (3) when you host the site on this VM, and try accessing it from your laptop, you get a white screen ?

Comment: site is https and certificate is invalid, so i am forwarding to normal website(http)

Comment: since the website is a banking internal website, i cannot run it in my laptop

Comment: Can you access it from a different VM in your data center? we gotta know if the (1) issue is with the IE on the VM (2) the issue is for every IE, everywhere in the world

Comment: all vm having same issue

Comment: Only in bank client environment IE having issue, non banking envorment laptop and other laptop there is no issue

Comment: i have edited the question and voted it up so that more users get more attention to it... can you also update the question with (1) your VM OS & version (2) your Angular version (3) any other detail which you'd like to share regarding your envornment

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug relating to zone.js and the IE Developer Tools.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31723

The development workaround is to add this flag before loading zone.js

```js
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```